# Ios style Swipe delete animation in phonegap

Tags: javascript, cordova

need to implement ios style swipe delete animation in phonegap.jquery plugin,Javascript setInterval doesnt get me safisfactory results.Css transitions/hover not supported on phonegap.Any pointers as to how can implement that delete button hide/show animation(swipe on delete) found in native ios app .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're interested in plugins, check this out [IOS Swipe delete button](https://github.com/ankane/swipeout) and [here](http://ankane.github.io/swipeout/demo.html) is the demo.

Also check [jQuery mobile swipe](http://api.jquerymobile.com/swipe/).

Comment: In ios,the button image shows/hides in parts.  eg notes app .